# Remove Duplicates in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate values from my array, the below array is what I need to alter:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Array
            (
                [milestone] => Milestone
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Array
            (
                [axis] => Axis
                [milestone] => Milestone
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [brand] => Array
            (
                [axis] => Axis
            )
    )

)
```

The end result should be this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [axis] => Axis
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [milestone] => Milestone
    )
)
```

This is what i have at the moment but it won't work.

```
foreach( $out_product_brands as $p_brands )
{
    foreach( $p_brands as $brands )
    {
        $brand[] = $brands;
    }
}
print_r($brand);
```

Could I get some help please.

Comment: share your try, you can start from foreach .

Comment: I have edited my post to include what I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicate keys, this is the code you need:

```
$allKeys = [];
$result = [];

foreach($brand as $index => $rec) {
    $newRec = []
    foreach($rec['brand'] as $key => $val) {
        if(!isset($allKeys[$key])) {
            $newRec[$key] = $val;
            $allKeys[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    if(count($newRec)) {
        $result[] = $newRec;
    }
}
```

If you want to remove only value duplicates this is more complicated, you need to specify logic - what to do with duplicate keys with different values.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i just realised I had the wrong array to work from. All updated now.

Comment: so the second code must work, I did not run it so some minor issues are possible

Comment: Whats the second foreach for?

Comment: okay I edited the code, since you changed array structure there is no need to keep one array and use unset(), the result will be still slightly different, because your first element is 'milestone' and second is 'axis', if you just remove dups, you cannot expect order change

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. How could I achieve this output?
[0] => Array
                (
                    [slug] => axis
                    [name] => Axis
                )